# ASP.NET MVC Security Check List

Tags: appsec, web-application, source-code, asp.net

I am planning to start a new web site on ASP.NET MVC 2 (3).

Does anybody have a *full* (if possible) **check list** of actions or approaches I should go through to avoid *most* security issues?

Comment: Related [Guidance for HTTPS-only sites](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/gui)

Comment: @makerofthings it's useful and good question

Answer (score 6):

Based on this [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx), I'm using POSTs for all my JSON data.  This underscores a few items in the [Codevanced](http://codevanced.net/post/ASPNET-MVC-security-checklist.aspx) checklist pasted here.

Comment: That blog post is a great illustration of JSON prototype hijacking.  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 5):

Barry Dorans, author of [Beginning ASP.NET Security](http://isbn.nu/0470743654), provides some good material on the subject. I read his book and he covers a lot of ASP.NET MVC specific material.

If you are looking for a check list of application security controls, be sure to also check out the [OWASP ASVS](http://owasp-asvs.googlecode.com) project.

Comment: Well, there's a chapter on it, but most of the book is core concepts which cover both webforms and MVC. Thanks for the recommendation :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a video series on how to hack proof your asp.net sites, it is two videos of about 50min where he also includes an introduction to the topic, he also includes examples, I havn't seen all of it yet, but I think it will cover some of your questions, or atleast give you som inspiration.

http://vimeo.com/28284123

Comment: Hi @psalomonsen, welcome to [security.se]! Can you please edit your answer to include a summary, instead of just linking? See the [FAQ], and [answer].