# Guidance for implementors of HTTPS-only sites (Server side)

Tags: web-application, tls, configuration, defense

The recent trend in HTTPS attacks is to attack the HTTP protocol.  What should I do to increase my site's security if the only protocol I want is HTTPS?

Some easy to implement ideas are

- Implement [HTTPS Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)
- Issue the authentication page over SSL
- Use HTML Form-posts for the login page's submit button not CSS DIV's

  - ... why? the user can't see the target URL when they hover
- Permit the client to cache the navigation page, as this will deter certain MITM attacks
- Use SSL-Only cookies
- Use an [I-Frame Buster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-) and the [X-Frames-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header
- Edit the cipher list to [only use RC4, AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/what-ciphers-should-i-use-in-my-web-server-after-i-configure-my-ssl-certificate/7621#7621) or [PFS](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7690/396)

More advanced/technical options may include

- Use [DNSSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=dnssec) to [protect vulnerable users](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6827/396)
- Use SSL Only Cookies everywhere
- Use [HTTPS padding](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7738/396) on all AJAX data
- Only issue the "session key" over HTTPS
- Send off-site links [to an intermediate page](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/8011/396)

Options that may break things (such as the user experience)

- Disallow web browsers that:

  - ...don't clearly indicate the TLS status in the URL
  - ...are subject to [IDN attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=idn)
  - [...are unpatched](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2021/396)
- Disallow port 80
- Only allow redirects from a whitelisted set of domains.  Don't permit someone to link to your site, and force the user to type in the HTTPS URL
- Use a private certificate for all operations for that site.  Issue the thumbprint (or RootCA) over a SSL connection

> What are your thoughts on a website that implements some or all of these techniques?
>
> What  additional techniques would you recommend?  (e.g. Use / Don't use OpenID, certain HTTP header directives, etc)

Comment: Related [Pros and Cons of Site-wide SSL](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258/wha)

Comment: Note: `X-Frame-Options` is [deprecated](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Limitations_2) in favor of [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) ([Level 2 Spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/CSP2/))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main ones are:

- **Use SSL sitewide.** Don't offer anything over http.  Instead, any connection via http should immediately redirect to the main site's landing page via https.
- **Use HTTPS Strict Transport Security.** This will tell users' browsers: please, only connect to me over https.  This defends against sslstrip and similar man-in-the-middle attacks.
- **Set the secure flag on all cookies.**  This will ensure that the cookies will only be sent over a https channel, never over an insecure http link.
- **Avoid third-party active content served over http.**  Don't load external active content over http.  Make sure that any CSS, Javascript, widgets, analytics, or ads that you load from third-party sources are loaded over https.

  - Potentially better yet, you can consider making your own copy and serving these resources from your own server if possible, so you don't need to load them from a third-party source.  In many cases you can avoid loading CSS, Javascript libraries, or widgets from third-party sources simply by storing a copy on your own server.
  - For analytics, note that Google Analytics does support https.
  - Ads are the hardest part.  If you use ads, you may not have any choice but to accept third-party ads over http, which is a security risk.  If you do, serve the ads in an iframe (do not use SCRIPT SRC to integrate the ads into your page).

  It is OK to load images hosted on a third-party host as long as they are loaded over HTTPS (to avoid mixed-content warnings).

I think if you do these four things, you'll cover most of the issues.  The rest are details that can be evaluated on a site-specific basis, but they are probably secondary in importance (in my opinion).

If you want to get fancy, you can look at certificate pinning and similar emerging technology, but starting with the above four is already a significant enough project.

Comment: If images are loaded over HTTPS from a third party, then is there any real security benefit to hosting them yourself?  What security breach can occur with an image over HTTPS?

Comment: @JustinCloud, you are right.  There's nothing wrong with loading images from third-party sites (if they are loaded over HTTPS).  I will edit my answer accordingly -- thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

#### User's Security

- You are missing one extremely **important** thing: CSRF mitigation.

  Be sure to [fully understand](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Prevention_Measures_That_Do_NOT_Work) the related problems. Tldr: in **addition** to the authorization token (e.g. session cookie), you need a challenge  **per** action to identify if the action is intended by the user or unintended.
- Fix [JSONP leaks](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/).
- [`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers#mw-content-text), on all pages to prevent MIME sniffing,  [**especially**](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12916/2379) for user-generated pages.
- [Content Security Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy).
- Ensure [secure "reset password"](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/1943/2379) mechanism to prevent people from resetting other people's password and gaining fraudulent access.
- Show a **huge** **huge** warning when users use weak passwords, or not accept it altogether.
- Train users (perhaps via an arrow image on every page pointing to the green bar) to check whether your pages are loaded with HTTPS. If they ever use a browser that does not support HSTS, at least they would notice that HTTPS is missing.

---

#### Server's / User's Security

- Ensure that secrets are not leaked due to [timing](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html) [attacks](http://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/).

---

#### User's Privacy

- Applying padding to only ajax is insufficient. To [protect your users against network monitoring](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/faq#threats), **all requests and responses** must be data padded. Requests do not need to be time-padded, but responses must.
- Fix history leaking due to [variance in the timings for responses](http://sip.cs.princeton.edu/pub/webtiming.pdf):

  > Suppose that Alice is surfing the Web, and she visits Bob’s Web
  >   site at `http://www.bob.com`. Bob wants to find out whether
  >   Alice has visited Charlie’s Web site (`http://www.charlie.
  >   com`).
  >
  > First, Bob looks at Charlie’s site, and picks a file that any visitor
  >   to the site will have seen. Let’s say Bob picks the file containing
  >   Charlie’s corporate logo, at `http://www.charlie.com/`
  >   logo.jpg. Bob is going to determine whether the logo file is in
  >   Alice’s Web cache. If the file is in her cache, then she must have
  >   visited Charlie’s Web site recently.
  >
  > Bob writes a Java applet that implements his attack, and embeds
  >   it in his home page. When Alice views the attack page, the
  >   Java applet is automatically downloaded and run in Alice’s browser.
  >   The applet measures the time required to access `http://www.
  >   charlie.com/logo.jpg` on Alice’s machine, and reports this
  >   time back to Bob. If the time is less than some threshold (say, 80
  >   milliseconds), Bob concludes that Alice has been to Charlie’s site
  >   recently; if it is greater than the threshold, he concludes that she has
  >   not been to the site recently.

---

#### Server's Privacy

- Ensure invulnerability to [clock skew](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/76596/2379) attacks.

---

#### Availability

- User-based / IP-based throttling in the event of [DoS and DDoS](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/254/2379).

---

Other misc stuff which you can't fix (browser problems):

- [History leaking via HSTS](https://www.leviathansecurity.com/blog/the-double-edged-sword-of-hsts-persistence-and-privacy/)