# Should I cancel my current credit card because of heartbleed vulnerability?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, credit-card, heartbleed

I recently looked at my local credit union bank and they said that their site is not vulnerable to heart bleed. However, I have used my credit card in many websites such as grubhub, amazon, some charity organizations, so the credit card data can be exploited. I want to have some expert opinion before I act?

PS: I looked at [What should end-users do about Heartbleed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55083/what-should-end-users-do-about-heartbleed) but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: I would say it depends.  Most credit card companies won't hold you responsible for something like this.  Your credit card would have only been compromise when you submitted the form, in most cases, what actually is stored is just an authorization token.  Granted ALL traffic from the compromised certificate could be decrypted, the amount of data your talking about, would be enormous.

Comment: So, essentially this would be an overkill. Moreover, VISA insurance should cover fraudulent charges.

Comment: If none of the answers there mention this, then apparently you don't. There is no list of "what should end-users not bother doing".