# CNN Money Portfolio and Heartbleed

Tags: tls, passwords, heartbleed

Is/was CNN Money Portfolio ever vulnerable to heartbleed? It states 256 bit SSL bank level encryption on the website..

Comment: possible dup: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55083/what-should-end-users-do-about-heartbleed

Answer (score 0):

rule of thump:

- if  open-source-server (e.g. apache, nginx, lighttpd et al)
- AND if tls 1.2 is available
- then the service was most probably affected by heartbleed