# Heart Bleeding Bus

Tags: web-browser

This may be a unwise question, but I'll ask anyhow. I have been analysis relatively a bit about the Heart Bleed vulnerability, and I'm curious as to whether it only affects web applications or could affect any routers?

Comment: Also, if you really meant "routers" in the professional sense, see [Heartbleed and Routers/ASAs/other](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/55085/2630). Not just webservers are affected, clients using OpenSSL are [affected](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/55119/2630) just as bad](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/55249/2630).

Answer (score 0):

It can affect any application web or otherwise which is complied with one of the vulnerable versions of openssl.. wget Linux command for example is vulnerable to client side exploits.